# How to get one of observable field's validation result in the computed field using Knockout Validation framework

Tags: knockout-validation

i have a view model defined following:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.identityCode = ko.observable().extend({ required: true, maxLength: 18, minLength: 15 });
    self.gender = ko.computed(function() {
        // get gender information from the identiy code here
    });
    self.birthdate = ko.computed(function() {
       // get birthdate information from the identity code here
    });
    self.form_onsubmit = function (form) {
        if (!self.isValid()) {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
};
```

as you can see the code above, the gender field and brithdate field are computed field which be got from the identity code. i just want to know how to get the validation result of identity code before doing it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validated observables are extended with an computed `isValid`. Therefore you can check the result with:

```
    self.gender = ko.computed(function() {
        // get gender information from the identiy code here
        if(self.identityCode.isValid()) {
          // do something with the code
        }
    });
```